# Remove element, and n following elements from list

Tags: python

<strike>I want to remove all elements from a list</strike> I want to iterate over a list, skipping elements that match some test, and a certain number of elements after that match. **eg.**

```
# skip 'foo' and 2 subsequent values

values = [1, 2, 3, 'foo', 'a', 'b', 6, 7, 'foo', 'x', 'y']

result = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

Is there a more elegant method to achieve this than iterating using a counter building a new list and skipping forwards `n` iteratations when the match is found? **ie.**

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 'foo', 'a', 'b', 6, 7, 'foo', 'x', 'y']

result = []

i = 0
while i < len(values):
    if values[i] == 'foo':
        i += 3
    else:
        result.append(values[i])
        i += 1

print result
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Please show the code you have so far.

Comment: How should it handle `[1, 'foo', 3, 'foo', 5, 6, 7]`?

Comment: That would return `[1, 5, 6, 7]` I suppose. The use case assumes that after each occurrence of `foo` will follow two values we don't care about.

Comment: @Acorn: You have two occurrences of foo. According to your rule, the second occurrence means that you don't care about the 5 and the 6.

Comment: @JohnMachin: With my problem, that will never be the case, but if it was, then most obvious solutions involving skipping would skip the second `'foo'`. A solution that would ignore `5, 6` in that case would be fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, how about a generator?

```
def iterskip(iterator, test, n):
    """Iterate skipping values matching test, and n following values"""
    iterator = iter(iterator)
    while 1:
        value = next(iterator)
        if test(value):
            for dummy in range(n):
                next(iterator)
        else:
            yield value

def is_foo(value):
    return value == 'foo'

print list(iterskip(values, is_foo, 2))
```

Comment: Nice solution, +1. A few nits: 1. Use `next(iterator)` instead of the obsolete `iterator.next()` (provided you are using at least 2.6). 2. Please don't use `_` as a variable name.  People tend to mistake this as some special syntax -- using `dummy` or similar instead avoids any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Just slice-delete.

```
>>> values = [1, 2, 3, 'foo', 'a', 'b', 6, 7, 'foo', 'x', 'y']
>>> values.index('foo')
3
>>> del values[3:3 + 3]
>>> values.index('foo')
5
>>> del values[5:5 + 3]
>>> values.index('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 'foo' is not in list
>>> values
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

Comment: This is O(n^2) in the worst case, while the original code is O(n).

Comment: Certainly there's room for optimization, including using the `start` argument to `list.index()`.

Answer (score 1):

And now, a coroutine solution.

```
def countdown(val, count):
  curr = 0
  while True:
    now = (yield curr)
    if curr > 0:
      curr -= 1
    if now == val:
      curr = count

values = [1, 2, 3, 'foo', 'a', 'b', 6, 7, 'foo', 'x', 'y']
c = countdown('foo', 3)
c.next()
print [x for x in values if not c.send(x)]
```

Comment: Neat.  You could use `list(ifilterfalse(c.send, values))` in the last line. (I'm not suggesting this would be any better.)

Answer (score 1):

Write a simple function to work with del slices of the list:

```
import copy
def del_sublists(list, value, length, copy_list = False):
    if copy_list:
        list = copy.deepcopy(list)
    while value in list:
        del list[list.index(value):list.index(value) + (length + 1)]
    return list

a = [1, 2, 3, 'foo', 'a', 'b', 6, 7, 'foo', 'x', 'y']
print del_sublists(a, 'foo', 2)
print a
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

and same but not changing the variable:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 'foo', 'a', 'b', 6, 7, 'foo', 'x', 'y']
print del_sublists(a, 'foo', 2, copy_list = True)
print a
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 'foo', 'a', 'b', 6, 7, 'foo', 'x', 'y']
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your definition of elegant, and whether you want to do what your question title says (remove from a list i.e. not making a new list).

The first function below safely mutates the existing list by iterating backwards and deleting the unwanted stuff. The second function iterates forwards using `list.index` until the marker is not found (IOW what Ignacio's answer suggested). The third function is a modified version of the first, assuming that the question is taken literally e.g. `['foo', 'foo', 1, 2]` is reduced to `[]`, not `[2]`.

Code:

```
def inplace_munge_1(alist, query, size):
    for i in xrange(len(alist) - 1, -1, -1):
        if alist[i] == query:
            del alist[i:i+size]

def inplace_munge_2(alist, query, size):
    start = 0
    while True:
        try:
            i = alist.index(query, start)
        except ValueError:
            return
        del alist[i:i+size]
        start = i

def inplace_munge_3(alist, query, size):
    marker = len(alist)
    delpos = []
    for i in xrange(len(alist) - 1, -1, -1):
        if alist[i] == query:
            for j in xrange(min(i + size, marker) - 1, i - 1, -1):
                delpos.append(j)
            marker = i
    for j in delpos:
        del alist[j]

funcs = [inplace_munge_1, inplace_munge_2, inplace_munge_3]

tests = [
    [],
    [1],
    ['foo'],
    [1, 2, 3, 'foo', 'a', 'b', 6, 7, 'foo', 'x', 'y'],
    ['foo', 'foo', 1, 2, 3],
    ]

fmt = "%-15s: %r"    
for test in tests:
    print
    print fmt % ("Input", test)
    for func in funcs:
        values = test[:]
        func(values, 'foo', 3)
        print fmt % (func.__name__, values)
```

Output:

```
Input          : []
inplace_munge_1: []
inplace_munge_2: []
inplace_munge_3: []

Input          : [1]
inplace_munge_1: [1]
inplace_munge_2: [1]
inplace_munge_3: [1]

Input          : ['foo']
inplace_munge_1: []
inplace_munge_2: []
inplace_munge_3: []

Input          : [1, 2, 3, 'foo', 'a', 'b', 6, 7, 'foo', 'x', 'y']
inplace_munge_1: [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
inplace_munge_2: [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
inplace_munge_3: [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]

Input          : ['foo', 'foo', 1, 2, 3]
inplace_munge_1: []
inplace_munge_2: [2, 3]
inplace_munge_3: [3]
```

Answer (score 0):

A good solution using a defined function:

```
def special_remove(my_list, item, start=0):
    try:
        pos = my_list.index(item, start)
        return special_remove(my_list[:pos] + my_list[pos+3:], item, pos)
    except ValueError:
        return my_list
```

And using the function with your data:

```
>>> values = [1, 2, 3, 'foo', 'a', 'b', 6, 7, 'foo', 'x', 'y']
>>> special_remove(values, 'foo') [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

Good thing about this code is that it won't fail even if you want to remove out-of-range elements, for example:

```
>>> values = [1, 'foo']
>>> special_remove(values, 'foo')
[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional version:

It's a bit messy, though.

```
def unfold(f, x):
    while True:
        try:
            w, x = f(x)
        except TypeError:
            raise StopIteration
        yield w

def test(info):
    values, cur_values, n = info
    length = len(values)

    if n == length:
        return None
    elif n == length-1:
        cur_values = cur_values + [values[n]]
    elif values[n] == "foo" and n < len(values)-2:
        n += 3

    return (cur_values, (values, cur_values + [values[n]], n+1))

values = [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 6, 7, 'foo', 'x', 'y', 2 , 6 , 7, "foo", 4 , 5, 6, 7]
results = list(unfold(test, (values, [], 0)))[-1]
print results
```

Output: [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 6, 7, 2, 6, 7, 6, 7]